# Running js on the php buffer content

Tags: php, javascript, dom, buffer, v8

i would like to do some JQuery stuffs on the content of the php buffer before sending the content of the buffer. I have this code:

```
<?php ob_start() ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Titre</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet/ucss" href="style.css" />

    </head>
    <body>
           //some html and php code
    </body>   
</html>
<?php $bufferContent = ob_get_clean(); ?>
```

Also I'd like to do some DOM stuff with JQuery on the content of the $bufferContent var.
I already know the V8JS PECL extension but i don't know how to use it with JQuery and DOM function.
Thanks for help and excuse my english.

Comment: Why Javascript? If you want to manipulate the DOM, use PHP's DOMDocument. Better yet, just build the HTML you want using normal PHP.

Comment: I want to use js because the function i'd like to use have to be available on both client and server. As there will be a lot of function, it would be better to use only one language on both side.

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you need help with. I can *guess* that you want help with using the V8JS PECL extension with JQuery and DOM. We can't give you a tutorial here - only answer questions. I recommend that you google for "V8JS PECL jquery DOM tutorial" and read everything that you can find. If you still have questions after that, then come back.

Answer (score 0):

Remember the basics - PHP runs on server and JS (jQuery too) runs in the user's browser. You can not run jQuery on the server side (only if you start browser there :)), but it is useless)

Comment: I know that and i realize that this is not current. Nevertheless it exists js solution as Node.js and V8js. V8js is a PECL extension which allows you to run js from php with the V8 engine. So my question is how to use Jquery DOM functions on the buffer content.

Comment: @Hugo Dellinger does it really make sense to run this on server? Sorry, I knew about extensions, but on my memory there were not so "powerfull" as browser's verion of js.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PHPQuery](https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) to run most JQuery commands.

However to run commands that use certain elements like document / window / etc you will need not only a JavaScript engine (v8js) but a DOM to work with the engine. For that there is [Env-JS](http://www.envjs.com/) and [Node-JS](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom).

You will have to load that into v8 before loading [jquery-min.js](http://jquery.com/).